# Converting lines to points in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, line, convert, point-creation

I am working to extract surface reflectance from the image collection, and I have only line geometry representing the central line of the river. I would like to convert the line into points and each point should be 500m in GEE. Then I will be able to extract the pixel value based on the computed points.

Answer (score 2):

The function below should work if you input a lineFeature and define the count (e.g. amount of points to achieve a 500m spacing).

```
function lineToPoints(lineString, count) {
  var length = lineString.length();
  var step = lineString.length().divide(count);
  var distances = ee.List.sequence(0, length, step)

  function makePointFeature(coord, offset) {
    var pt = ee.Algorithms.GeometryConstructors.Point(coord);
    var coords = pt.coordinates(); // set coords as feature property
    
    return new ee.Feature(pt).set({'offset': offset,
                                  'lat': coords.get(0),
                                  'lon': coords.get(1)
    })
  }
  
  var lines = lineString.cutLines(distances).geometries();

  var points = lines.zip(distances).map(function(s) {
    var line = ee.List(s).get(0);
    var offset = ee.List(s).get(1)
    return makePointFeature(ee.Geometry(line).coordinates().get(0), offset)
  })
  
  points = points.add(makePointFeature(lineString.coordinates().get(-1), length))

  return new ee.FeatureCollection(points);
}
```